# x4j-analytic and muti-page excel reports with charts

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have used JXLS to try to create a multi-page report with a chart in each sheet but it failed.
Imagine a scenario where you have data about monthly sales about a few products,
so each tab would be a Month and then each month would have a chart about sales of the products.

So I am looking for a Java API that can clone a template chart and put copies of these into separate sheets/tabs.

I was able to create the multiple sheets based on a template file, and was able to get the chart to be copied to each sheet from the template, but the "range literal string" that needs to be put into the Chart series was not dynamic in that it had the same reference to the first sheet from the original template.

When I spoke to the Author of JXLS he said he will try to look into it, but it has been over 1.5 years now and no progress.

My question is if anybody knows if "x4j-analytic" can create such reports.

I hope the author of this project: jbaliuka, can make some comments on this.

There is another java excel reporting project called JETT, I posed the same question on their forum/mailing list, but the author Randy Gettman does not seem to be actively looking at it.

Sincerely,

Palu

Answer (score 1):

x4j-analytic library does not support dynamic sheets too. I normally use pivot with dynamic columns to display such data, pivot charts  should work too. Dynamic sheets might be useful to workaround Excel limitations for very huge reports but I did not have such problem in practice and this feature is unimplemented.